# HTML text input rounded when numbers entered

Tags: html, input, numbers, rounding

i'm developing a PHP application and i have one problem when i use HTML text inputs, and this is the first time where i deal with this case.
When i try to insert a float value as 34.4 in HTML text input to put it in MySQL DB, but when i go to my DB i find the value 35.
I don't know why this value is rounded, i do not use any function like ceil.
If someone can help me i'll be so thankful.

Comment: What format is the column?

Comment: in my DB it's Decimal

Comment: thanks bro you helped me to find the solution, the format of my column was DECIMAL(10,0), and it should be DECIMAL(10,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with decimal, the  default is DECIMAL(10, 0), you should specify the precision and scale, for example:

```
DECIMAL(10, 4)
```

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is *DECIMAL(M,D)*. The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows:

**M** is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)

**D** is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

**Reference:** 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Also, check this answer: [How do I interpret precision and scale of a number in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377174/how-do-i-interpret-precision-and-scale-of-a-number-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Set column type to float in Mysql

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in DB column type, it was DECIMAL(10,0) for this reason the MySQL rounded the float number to an INT number.