# Creating a Column for Price in Laravel Schema

Tags: php, laravel-5, schema

I want to create a column for price in a laravel schema.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cameras', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('condition');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Or is there an alternative data type I can use?  As I don't see anything for monetary value in the documentation.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem in storing them in `float` type? what's the need for a monetary data type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is 'decimal' type for your purpose it seems fine unless you don't want to save currency too:

```php
$table-> decimal('amount')
```

Available types are listed in documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#creating-columns

If you do want to save currency with price you will have to use string , or create a new column for currency-type can be another work around.

Comment: float can lead to precision issues. better to use `decimal`.

Comment: Decimals are what should be used, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768713/float-or-decimal-for-prices)

Comment: don't use float for prices, i can lead to several problems

Answer (score 35):

You can use decimal to precisely store price value:

```
$table->decimal('price', 9, 3);
```

> **Note** that 9 is the precision, like 1234567.89 has a precision of 9,
> And 3 is the number of decimal places, ie 123456.789 has a scale of 3
>
> In other words, if we use less decimal-places than 3, we can use remaining for real-number places.
> See also:
> [How do I interpret precision and scale of a number in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377174/how-do-i-interpret-precision-and-scale-of-a-number-in-a-database)

---

Alternatively, you can also use big integer and store the amount in basic monetary unit like cents. Like this:

```
$table->bigInteger('price');
```

So if we want to store let's say `$ 107.45` (107 dollars, 45 cents), we'd first *multiply it by 100* and store `10745` in the price column. And upon retrieval *divide by 100*.

> In other words, storing the lowest unit you think will be ever required, like storing Centi-meters instead of Meters (Centi is originally Greekish name for "0.01" number).

Comment: I believe you meant $table-> instead of $this-> ?

Comment: I would have edited, but don't like doing so with code. Thank you for the original response and thank you for updating! 

Comment: This seems like a better solution than the accepted answer